# How could I go about using code I found on Stack Overflow in a commercial product?

Tags: discussion, legal

I'd like to [Alexey-san's answer that contains code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625360/16587) on ["How to write `is_complete` template?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625105/how-to-write-is-complete-template) in my commercial product without "CC BY-SA 3.0".

The code is great, and would be useful for my product.

But I can't use it in the proprietary licensed product, because of "SA" condition of the CC license.

I'm sorry for posting such a legal question here, it's not a technical issue, but I don't know how to contact the author by another way.

I hope that Alexey-san may reply to this.

Comment: Before everyone jumps to close this as OT, take a closer look. This isn't a programming question. It's about whether the OP can use a solution from SO in a commercial product.

Comment: @Mysticial But, is that really a question we can answer?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Well, we can tell him that meta can't give him permission.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues and code ownership, not something the community can authoritatively answer.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I dunno about that. But I came *that* close to instinctively VTCing this as a programming question.

Comment: @Mysticial Me, too, actually!

Comment: Leave a comment asking for permission. I'm pretty sure that the original author can give you permission to do what you want with it.

Comment: @Linuxios That may not be enough; they may actually have to change the license (maybe by posting it on their site with a "Do whatever you want with it" license).

Comment: FYI, I disagree with this close reason. It's precisely the type of question Meta is here for.

Comment: You can always use it and not credit him ;)

Answer (score 6):

You must get permission from the copyright holder(s). That will be the author in all likelihood.

But Stack Exchange can not give you permission as they are licensees not the copyright holder.

Comment: So a comment like 'I'd like to use this code, can I?'

Comment: I doubt that Stack Exchange comments would hold up in court if it came to that...

Comment: @Undo Nothing less than an email would do I think.